# How to get D3 Multiple Y-Axes Ticks to Line Up?

Tags: d3.js, time-series, yaxis

I'm trying to show multiple Y-Axes on a time series with multiple lines. You'll see in this screenshot on the right there are Y-Axis tick labels shown for each of the four color-coded lines.

I want to always show exactly six ticks/labels. Depression, Sleep Disturbance, Daily Health are perfect! They are showing 6 labels. I want "Steps" to show up on the exact same marks. In this case, It would need to be something like 0, 12000, 26000, 39000, 52000, and 65000. Roughly. You get the idea. I cannot figure out how to get all of the Y-Axes to show up in exactly a count of 6 ticks so they line up nice.

Note: there are many time series to display, and depending on the user's data, the Y-domains may be different (one person may have up to 60,000 steps, another user just 5,000). So all this information is determined programmatically and dynamically, I can't hard code things.

Any help on what to do?

[image: D3 Custom Programmed Multiple Y-Axes Time Series]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [.tickValues()](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickValues), where you set the axis' values explicitly.  Based on the person's data, create an array of 6 values [0, (max * 1/5), (max * 2/5), ..., (max * 5/5)], and use this as the argument for tickValues